# Can we make materialized view with group by statement

Tags: cassandra

I want to create materialzed view on table having group by using

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW alltimehigh AS SELECT rollno,count(marks)
FROM student
GROUP BY rollno;
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:80 mismatched input 'GROUP' expecting K_PRIMARY (...,count(marks) FROM student [GROUP] BY...)
```

Can't we do this?

Comment: Adding the actual error would be a useful start ;)

Comment: driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:80 mismatched input 'GROUP' expecting K_PRIMARY (...,count(marks) FROM student [GROUP] BY...)

Comment: can you include your base table definition? GROUP BY is for SELECTs but we can possibly help point to better functionality if you are describing what you are trying to do. You will probably need to create a 2nd table but you can possibly just make a GROUP BY select query with count() aggregate